# C line wrap indentation rules in emacs

Tags: emacs

I am currently working on a C project with other people where they have decided that the indent style for wrapped lines is to indent 8 spaces, instead of where the opening parenthesis/bracket is, e.g.

```
if (long cond 1 &&
        long cond 2 &&
        long cond 3) {
    //do stuff
}
```

instead of

```
if (long cond 1 &&
    long cond 2 &&
    long cond 3) {
    //do stuff
}
```

However, emacs defaults to the latter and I don't know how to change it to behave like the former. Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your `.emacs`:

```
(c-set-offset 'arglist-cont-nonempty 8)
```